# WHERE clause followed by JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I have a very large table of values. Let's call that table `big`. I have a somewhat smaller table called `small`. I would like to join these tables, but only on specific values within `big`.

I could get the values by saying

```
SELECT a,b FROM big WHERE foo='bar';
```

I would like to join that result with `small`, saying something like:

```
SELECT a,b FROM big WHERE foo='bar' 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b as small_b,c,d FROM small) ON big.b=small.small_b
```

I don't want to pull everything in `big`, because that's a lot of stuff and takes half a minute. I just need that small subset. How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: I've edited my query to match the `WHERE` clause going at the end. Even though I call one of the tables `big`, it actually has under 500,000 rows. The test case query I was using  did not use any values found in `big` (big has no value where foo='bar'), and the query still took over seven seconds. Is this really normal? It seems extremely slow to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mistake the syntax of SQL for the flow of execution performed by the RDBMS engine: this query

```
SELECT a,b FROM big b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b as small_b,c,d FROM small) ON big.b=small.small_b
WHERE b.foo='bar'
```

will be optimized to perform a join only to the rows of `big` filtered by the `foo='bar'` condition, not on the entire `big`, by any query optimizer that is worth its salt, despite the fact that the `WHERE` clause appears textually after the `JOIN`.

You may want to rewrite this without an inner `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT t1.a as big_a, t1.b as big_b, t2.b as small_b, t2.c, t2.d
FROM big t1
LEFT JOIN small t2 ON t1.b = t2.b
WHERE t1.foo='bar'
```

Comment: Would you by any chance update your response for my edit? I know I shouldn't change the question like that, but I am trying to figure out why it is so slow...

Comment: @MirroredFate I assume that you have an index on `foo`, right? Otherwise it would be a full table scan to see that the joining is to be done to no rows at all.

Comment: I thought I did. I just checked, and apparently I only had foo as part of a unique key... So I began began the index operation for foo, and it is still running... That should help. Assuming everything works, I'll let you know how long the query takes after the indexing operation.

Comment: Mk, unfortunately, the query now takes between 9 and 20 seconds.

Comment: @MirroredFate How long does a query `SELECT a,b FROM big b WHERE foo='bar'` take after adding the index? It should be nearly instantaneous.

Comment: 0.0011 seconds. This is why I am confused.

Comment: @MirroredFate That's very strange... Could you try adding `AND big.foo='bar'` to the end of the join condition?

Comment: Already tried that. It still takes upwards of 7 seconds. :/
Sometimes as much as 30 seconds.

Comment: @MirroredFate Out of curiosity, could you also try making it an inner join, and/or simplifying the query to remove the nested `SELECT`? I suspect that the optimizer gets confused somewhere (query optimizers are like that :-) so making the structure as simple as possible might help.

Comment: INNER JOIN: 8.2 seconds |

INNER JOIN without a SELECT: Column b is ambiguous |
 
INNER JOIN with WHERE: 8.4 seconds |

Doing an EXPLAIN yields "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const table" for 'select_type' 'PRIMARY' and for 'select_type' 'DERIVED' it says "Using index"

Comment: @MirroredFate I tried rewriting the query to drop the inner `select` without triggering ambiguity. Could you try it and see the timing?

Comment: That's the ticket! Query took 0.0011 seconds. Excellent, and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simplifed, you can't put a `WHERE` clause before the `JOIN`, it needs to go after it according to the syntax rules. The optimizer will figure the best order of execution out and won't necessarily execute things in the order you list them anyway.

```
SELECT big.a, big.b, small.b as small_b, small.c, small.d 
FROM big 
LEFT JOIN small
  ON big.b = small.b
WHERE foo = 'bar';
```

EDIT: If the query is slow with no or minimal hits, the likely cause is missing indexes on `foo`.

Add an index on `foo`, and both `big.b` and `small.b` and you should see speedup.