# SQL: joining 3 tables

Tags: sql

Sorry for this simple question, but looked through some old questions and couldn't find the answer I needed.

I have 3 tables all with user_id (though named differently in each table), and I want to join them together with conditions from each table.  I've only done JOIN with 2 tables before, and curious why my below query is throwing an error.

```
SELECT c.user_id FROM
    (SELECT userid from database_all where date='2013-09-03' AND college='Harvard') a
JOIN
    (SELECT userid2 FROM database_users) b
ON 
    a.userid = b.userid2
JOIN
    (SELECT user_id FROM database_courses where num_courses < 3 ) c
ON 
    b.userid2 = c.user_id
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: What is the error? What SQL DBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like MySQL, probably, if only because of the yyyy-mm-dd format. I don't see anything syntactically invalid though.

Comment: it's a company-internal dbms, but error message keeps saying missing EOF

Comment: great dbms as I can see !

Comment: @user1899415 Do you get the error when you execute the query or in some other system?  EOF seems like a VBA error in MS Access or Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should solve your problem :

```
SELECT 
    database_courses.user_id 
FROM 
    database_all 
JOIN
    database_users  ON database_all.userid=database_users.userid2
JOIN
    database_courses  ON database_users.userid2=database_courses.userid
WHERE
    database_all.date='2013-09-03' AND database_all.college='Harvard' AND database_courses.num_courses < 3
```

Comment: I get the same "missing EOF" error after line 4, apparently it doesn't like "AS a"

Comment: Glad to know it worked ! Now you know you can't use aliases with your company-internal dbms ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
SELECT c.user_id FROM database_all AS a 
JOIN database_users AS u ON a.userid=u.userid2
JOIN database_courses AS c ON b.userid2=c.user_id
WHERE a.data='2013-09-03' 
AND a.college='Harvard'
AND c.num_courses<3
```

Generally you need to put your `WHERE` clause at the end, and the `DBMS` will optimize the query for you.

I actually had a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000389/where-clause-followed-by-join).

The MySQL documentation also covers this in their section about [`SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

As you can see, the `FROM` clause with the table references comes directly before the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
Select distinct u.user_id -- I think you might not want the same userId repeated ???
From database_users u 
   join database_courses c
      On c.userId = u.UserId
         And c.num_courses < 3
   join database_all a
      On a.UserId = u.UserId
         And a.date='2013-09-03' 
         And a.college='Harvard'
```

Comment: It's pretty likely that userid2 is the primary and and thus distinct, so given the joins he is doing, I don't think he should need distinct...?